# Hillman and Hoggat's Binomial Generalization

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

In proving Gould's "Star of David" conjecture, Hillman and Hoggat generalized the binomial coefficient. First, they demand that $a_n$ be a sequence with the two properties that

$$\gcd(a_m, a_n) \mid a_{m+n}$$

$$\gcd(a_m, a_{m+n}) \mid a_{n}$$

The then say $b(n, 0) = 1$, and 
$$b(n, k) = \frac{a_n}{a_k} b(n-1, k-1)$$

Using the constraints on $a_n$, they are able to show that SoD holds for $b(n,k)$ and therefore holds for both the standard binomial as well as variants of it (including the [Fibonomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonomial_coefficient)).

They use the claim that $b(n,k)$ will be an integer. This is what confuses me. If $a_n$ is the $n$th prime, then the constraints holds vacuously, but $b(n,k)$ is often times *not* an integer. I think I am missing something in my understanding of Hillman and Hoggat's constraint on $a_n$

The paper I am referencing is called "A Proof of Gould's Pascal Hexagon Conjecture".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n$ is the $n$th prime, it is not the case that $\gcd(a_n,a_n)\vert a_{n+n}$.

Comment: Thank you. I was erroneously presuming that m and n were always different.

Comment: Could h&h's constraint be stated simply as `gcd(a_n, a_m) = a_{gcd(n, m)}`?

Comment: Hmm, nice idea. It definitely seems possible that it’s equivalent, though I don’t immediately see the proof. (I haven’t looked at the paper closely enough to see if it would simplify the proof of their result or be sufficient, even if it turns out not to be equivalent.)